# Пенка или пенки?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Вопрос, вроде бы, глупый и простой, но однозначного ответа на него я найти не могу. А именно: как правильно - "пенки от варенья" или "пенка от варенья"?
Если обратиться к литературе, то можно встретить обе формы: *"Она обхватывает материнские колени, прижимается лицом к юбке, которая так упоительно пахнет пенками от варенья, и быстро, упрямо топает ногами"* (В. Катаев). Или, наоборот: 
*Так что всего милее для тебя, мальчишка?

В хлебе - горбушка, в капусте - кочерыжка,

В варенье - пенка,

А в школе - переменка!*
И все-таки, как правильно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Интересный вопрос...
Раньше как-то не задумывался. Но попробую ответить...

Тут дело, думаю, не столько в многократном снятии (хотя и в нем тоже), сколько в цели процесса и его завершенности.

Если без кулинарной цели или как побочный продукт - пенка (снял пенку с супа, молока), хотя и тут возможно множественное, если "пенка" рваная, не сплошная (например, от мясного или рыбного бульона).

Как кушанье (именно в этом случае обычно имеет место неоднократное снятие "пенки"), то только множественное - "пенки": "молочные пенки с сиропом", "печеные яблоки с клубничными пенками" и т.д. Кстати, в некоторых кочевых культурах молочную пенку используют для приготовления совсем не сладких блюд, типа сыра. Вспомнил об этом потому, что в этой фразе случае уместно употребить и множественное, и единственное число "пенка" - как собирательное, подобно тому, как используется "торговля рыбой, мясом, яйцом".

В идиоме "снимать пенки" (извлекать выгоду, обычно сомнительным путем или неправомерную) - только множественное.

Во всех остальных случаях (особенно в профессиональном жаргоне) - пенка: пенка на губах (запекшаяся пена - обычно применительно к лошадям), глазурная пенка и т.д. - только единственное.

Может быть, что-то упустил.

Answer (score 0):

У варенья может быть одна пенка. Следовательно, было бы правильно: пенка от варенья или пен***ки*** от варе***ний***.

Однако в словаре Ушакова к этому слову приводится в толковании  такой  пример: Пенка - Застывающий верхний слой сиропа при варке варенья. ***Пенки*** с клубничного варенья. (Заметьте, во мн.ч.).
Видимо, мн.ч. обусловлено тем, что саму пенку в процессе варки снимают несколько раз, по мере ее образования.